# Calendar live tile no longer showing event title

Tags: calendars, lumia-denim-update

I use the medium size live tile for my calendar on my home screen, and am used to it showing the title and time of my next appointment; however, after my phone updated to Denim this morning, I've noticed that only the time of the start of the appointment is shown; the full event title is only shown in the large live tile (differences shown in the 2 screenshots below); has anyone else observed this? Is there an option to revert to the old behaviour - I don't really want to have the calendar as a large tile!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you opened and closed calendar; and tried to "re-sync" your emails?

Comment: I have Denim on my 920, and the Calendar live definitely shows event title on the medium tile. Try re-pinning the live tile, as suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to:

- re-pin the livetile (should help)
- resync the calendar
- create new appointments and check if they have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I just resized the tile and it came right back.